# Android mutableListof(pair(k,v) --> pair value empty if I clear variable but I add mutableListof before clear()... why will be empty?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using mutableListOf with pair() but I don't understand how and why it works.

```
var x = mutableListOf<Pair<String, ArrayList<Long>>>()
val y= ArrayList<Long>()
val testNumber : Long = 5  
y.add(testNumber )

x.add(Pair("testString",testNumber))
Log.i(TAG, "$x")  //--> x = [testString,[5]]

y.clear()

Log.i(TAG, "$x")  // --> x = [testString,[]]  so my testNumber value is empty
```

Comment: The `Pair` has a _reference to_ the list; it doesn't have a _copy of_ the list.  If you keep modifying the list, the pair will show that modification, and so will a list containing the pair, and so on.

Comment: yes its true, maybe, i tried this 

val y= ArrayList<Long>()
val testNumber : Long = 5  
y.add(testNumber )

val d= y
log--> not empty
y.clear()
log-> empty 

so the bugbear is ArrayList(), but your answear is correct thx.

Comment: It's not `ArrayList`, really.  It's fundamental to the language.  If it were any other type that could be modified, the same thing would happen.  If you want to do modifications that aren't propagated, you have to do a _copy_ when you put it in another type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the code you entered should not compile because pair accepts the ArrayList and you are putting long.
 Now considerig this is a typo and in your code you entered y instead of testNumber in your pair in x,  You have added a reference to the Arraylist in your pair. And y and your reference in your pair points to same object at same memory location. so when you clear the y the data at that memory location gets cleared. And since your pair also point to same memory location which is already been cleared and hence you get the empty data. Its just like calling a person with his official name and nick name as both points to same person.

The solution should be to make a copy of the y before adding it to pair and add that copy to the pair. 
try

```
x.add(Pair("testString",ArrayList(y))
```

or you can manually make deepCopy of y and then enter it in x